# Deploying shinyapp with AWS db

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny

I have recently developed a shiny application for my organisation with AWS data source. But when I am trying to deploy the application, it’s showing-

```
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '##.2##.###.3#' (110)
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted.
```

I have whitelisted the IPs as mentioned in the documentation in 3.8.4 section. But still getting the error.

Kindly guide in this.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the AWS datasource directly (with say, `DBI`) or using an API (using, say `curl` or `httr`)?  If the former, this cannot be done (AFAIK): AWS, like (almost?) all database providers restrict access to local(ish) processes.  You will need to write an API to handle database requests.  if you're already using an API, we need far more information than you have given us so far.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to directly use the data from AWS. Nowhere, have I read that I have to use an API for the same. Can you guide me regarding the same.?